# <video> not playing in chrome unless developer tools window open

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-canvas

I have a video that is meant to autoplay when the website is loaded up (it's not my site, I'm just doing work on it). It works fine on firefox and other browsers, but on Chrome, it only works if I right click when it's loading, or it works if I have the developer tools window open when I click refresh. But left alone on Chrome, it just tries to load, then goes black after a few seconds. Same on tablets using Chrome. It's set up as follows:

```
<video id="bgvid" preload="metadata" type="video/mp4" autoplay="" loop="" height="auto" webkit-playsinline="">
<source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
<source src="/video.ogv" type="video/ogg"> 
<source src="/video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Has anyone experienced an issue like this before? I don't even know where to start, to be honest, so any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it. On Chrome, videos need the attribute 'muted', whereas when the site was created, they didn't. I added that, and it fixed it.